# Sub-Page handling in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

New to flask...I have an app I'm working on where I have competitions and teams, and any number of teams can belong to a particular competition. Models for competition, team, and competition teams below

```
class CompetitionTeam(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'CompetitionTeams'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    Competitions = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(u'Competitions.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    Teams = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(u'Teams.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    CreateDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

    Competition = db.relationship(u'Competition')
    Team = db.relationship(u'Team')


class Competition(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Competitions'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    Date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    Location = db.Column(db.String(120))
    CreateDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    LastModifiedDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Teams'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    Number = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    Website = db.Column(db.String(120))
    CreateDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    LastModifiedDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
```

I have routes for /competitions and /teams, and I'm able to add/delete competitions and teams with no problems. I have a template file for /competitions that has the add competition form on it and a list of existing competitions. What I'd like to be able to do is to support /competitions/, so that when I click one of the existing competitions in the list, it opens a sub-page and lists the teams currently assigned to that competition, and supplied a form to add teams to that competition. Any advice on how to approach this would be helpful. My form and view (thusfar) are below:

```
class CompetitionTeamForm(Form):
    competition = SelectField('Competition', coerce=int)
    team = SelectField('Team', coerce=int)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def validate(self):
        if not Form.validate(self):
            return False
        else:
            return True

@app.route('/competitions/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def manage_competition(id):

    form = CompetitionTeamForm()
    # should use current competition ID here instead of a selectfield, will refactor later
    form.competition.choices = [(a.id, a.name) for a in Competition.query.order_by('name')]
    form.team.choices = [(b.id, b.number) for b in Team.query.order_by('number')]
```

Just committed my current progress on this branch: https://github.com/jasonrahm/rrftc/tree/addTeamsToComp

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question with help from davidism...I was making it way harder than I needed to. Here's my (unfinished but working) route:

```
@app.route('/competitions/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def manage_competition(id):

    form = CompetitionTeamForm(request.values, competition=id)
    comp = Competition.query.get(id)
    form.competition = comp.Name
    form.team.choices = [(a.id, a.Number) for a in Team.query.order_by('Number')]

    user = session['username']

    if user is None:
        redirect(url_for('signin'))
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.validate() == False:
                return render_template('competition_details.html', form=form, id=id)
            else:
                postdata = request.values
                comp = int(postdata['competition'])
                team = int(postdata['team'])

                newteam = CompetitionTeam(competitions=comp, teams=team)
                db.session.add(newteam)
                db.session.commit()

                return redirect(url_for('manage_competition', id=id))

        elif request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('competition_details.html', form=form, id=id)
```

My template is also not done, but the functionality is there:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('manage_competition', id=id) }}" method=post>
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}


{{ form.team.label }}
{{ form.team }}


{{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

I am using QuerySelectField on the form for the team list, and hiding the competition field and not rendering it since it's passed in the URL as the sub-page.

```
class CompetitionTeamForm(Form):
    competition = HiddenField('Competition')
    team = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: Team.query.all(), get_label='Number')
    submit = SubmitField('Add Team')
```

Hopefully this helps another newbie trying to put all the pieces together.